# Setting color property of text view with Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, text, colors, adt

I'm an absolute beginner at Eclipse ADT for Android, although I've done decades of software development. I'm building a very simple, first-time, Android application using Eclipse. I've positioned a simple Text object on it and want to specify the background color for it. I click on the object and can see all the properties of it in the properties box. I scroll down to the Background item and it shows a little button to the right, which in other IDEs would let me open up a dialog in which I can select a color. But clicking it does nothing.

SOME of the other properties do indeed let me click on its related button and bring up a dialog of selections, but not for the Background property and in fact not for MOST of the properties.

How do I get it to let me make a color selections?

Comment: So basically, you want to set the background of a textview on click on something ?

Comment: No. I'm at the design stage uwing Eclipse ADT for designing the user interface for the app. It shows a graphic of the smartphone and has "Palette" section that shows all thepossible UI objects. Normally I would be able to drag-n-drop any of those objects over onto the layout form. But when I do that, nothing happens. The UI object (e.g. a Button) does NOT end up in the layout and it also does not end up in the Compnent Tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of a button in android going to an XML file that is in the route:

Application/res/layout/activity_application

There you will find the XML structure of all the objects in the view, now you can put a property which allows you to change the background color of the object.

Example:

`<Button`

`android:id="@+id/idButton"`

`android:background="#000000"`

`android:textColor="#000000"`

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"



/>
```

Also you can chanche the color of the text. 
Greetings

Comment: That shows how to do it within the actual code of the objects. But Eclipse allows you to build views and add tings like views and text objects and such and to modify their properties via a properties window/dialog. The problem is that the properties dialog, although it lists things like "background" as a property, and it has a little button to the right of it that would normally (in other IDEs like Visual Studio) bring up a dialog of color selections, clicking on that button in Eclipse does nothing.

How do I change the color using the properties dialog in Eclipse?

Comment: I think Eclipse doesn´t allows you for change the color in that way, when you clic in the background property you can choose a resource for  modify the style, I never change the styles in that mode, sorry I hope that helps you

Comment: When I click the property in the properties box on Eclipse nothing at all happens. It does not bring up anything to make a selection. There are a very few of the properties that it DOES allow me to make selections. But in fact MOST of the properties, when clicked, do nothing at all.